# React Navigation: how to prevent stack from popping when dispatching openDrawer from outside of drawerNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**Snack**: https://snack.expo.io/Hkv4A8zjm

Follow these steps to replicate:

1. Press "Open Drawer" button on Page 1
2. Select page2 in the drawer menu
3. Press "Go to Page 3" on Page 2
4. Press "Open Drawer" on Page 3

**Current Behavior**

Currently, when you press "Open Drawer" on Page 3, the drawer opens as expected, *however the navigator takes you back to Page 2*, rather than leaving you on Page 3 where you opened the drawer from.

**Expected Behavior**

Perhaps this is less expected and more desired but I'd like to be able to open the menu without navigating back to Page 2. The use case is when I have pages that are not top-level, thus are not included in the drawer menu. However, I'd like the user to always have access to the drawer if they'd like to navigate elsewhere -- but if they close the menu without selecting another page, it should return them to where they left off, not navigate them back up the stack.

**Question**

Is there a way I can either resolve this issue, or another method to hiding screens from the drawer navigation but still allow them to be "pushable" from any screen in the drawer?

Comment: FWIW, I posted this on the repo but haven't heard anything there. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5129

Comment: I honestly don't get the use-case explanation here (perhaps only because I haven't used `DrawerNavigation` yet) but AFAIK the whole point of `createDrawerNavigation` is to include only the screens you want inside the `DrawerNavigation`, no? May be you could include `Page3` in the `createDrawerNavigation` as well, and render a _custom_ `DrawerComponent` where you only show the links to `Page1` and `Page2`?

Comment: @UzairA. that is an option, however doing would make Page3 be again a top level page, whereas I would like to push it over Page 2, rather than switch to Page3. I'd like to preserve a back action

Comment: Well, you can always write a custom back action too. :D In all seriousness though, that's all I could suggest since I haven't worked with `DrawerNavigation`. I hope you get the answer you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

**Try resetting the `stack` when you move from `page 2 to page 3`**

Below i am `navigating` to `login page` **set it to your desired page** just change the value of

`routeName: '//YOUR PAGE'`

**Use the below code for navigation :**

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [
              {
                type: 'Navigation/INIT',
                routeName: 'Login',
                params: {
                }
              }
            ]
          });
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

On `android` `back button` you can implement as suggested below **if it is a custom toolbar or something just navigate on onClick event**

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
  }

  handleBackButtonClick() {
     // NAVIGATE BACK TO PAGE 2
  }
```

Comment: The problem here is I want to be able to hit "back" to get from Page 3 to Page 2 and this reset action removes the ability to go back.

Comment: No , for that handle the back button click in it use normal navigation to navigate to page 2

Answer (score 0):

In your snack, your trying to open the drawer from `screen3`, which is not present in the drawer navigator, and that causes the trouble.

You'll need to rework the navigation structure of the app, for example like this: (snack: https://snack.expo.io/@vonovak/shallow-cake)

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    page2: { screen: Page2 },
    page3: { screen: Page3 },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);
const Navigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  page1: Page1,
  stack: Stack
});
```

Comment: While this works for this particular example, I probably didn't explain my use case the best. The problem is I don't know what screen will be opening Page 3, so I need it accessible from every page in the drawer navigation, hence the way I originally structured my navigation. 

What I'd prefer is for any screen NOT visible in the drawer, to PUSH on top of whichever screen navigates to it. But also from those pushed screens be able to open the drawer, while preserving the current stack (aka not popping). 

With your solution I'd have to create a stack for each drawer item...

Comment: yes, having a stack for each drawer item is likely the way to take. You might be able to keep the current structure and use some complicated `reset`s but I'd go with stacks inside the drawer.